# How to get content inside unordered list with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The html is like this:

```
<a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="Mylink.com"><font color="#547794"><u>My link Title</u></font></a>
```

I am able to extract the "a" tags but how do I extract the title "My link Title" inside the "a" tags?

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    link_str = str(link['href'])
    print(link_str)
```

Comment: `link.find('u').text`

Comment: @mama I'm  getting "no attribute text" I'm using import urllib.request

Comment: probably you are getting links without u's inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="Mylink.com"><font color="#547794"><u>My link Title</u></font></a>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html.encode(), 'html.parser').find('u').text
print(soup)
```